# Cannot run File explorer

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, crash

When i click on library, screen resolution, personalisation or even anything that is related to file explorer (my computer, control panel & e.t.c) "explorer.exe"  crashes and restarts.. and some why my desktop is scaled to 150% and i cant even fix it from display options.. Help please..
Since I cant try to do anything from control panel or any settings on my PC I need help from you guys

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this lets begins with the event viewer log,

To open the event viewer,

> Click Start -> Run -> eventvwr.exe and then
>
> Expand “Event Viewer”. Under “Windows Log” click on the “Application
>   Log”

and search for error filed for "explorer.exe" and get the "Faulting Application path", then remove/uninstall the specified application from the system and do a system restart and check whether this issue got fixed.